# How to properly access first full list inside a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Suppose I have the following list structure:

```
some_list=[['A001', 'A002'], ['A003', 'A004'], ['A005', 'A006']]
```

I am trying to access the first list inside this structure, the idea is that the returning attribute for first loop is a list, in order to get an iterable structure for the next loop:

```
for i in zip(*some_list)[0]:
    print(i)
    for element in some_list[0]:
        print(element)
```

Which returns:

```
#A001
#A001
#A002
#A002
#A001
#A002
```

First for-loop could return this list:

```
['A001', 'A002']
```

Second for-loop could return this:

```
'A001'
'A002'
```

How could I accomplish this structure?

Comment: `some_list[0]` ?

Comment: what's wrong with some_list[0]?

Comment: Just `some_list[0]`?

Comment: No `zip` required, you just want `some_list[0]`

Comment: It returns just the elements without any structure

Comment: I am trying to get the full list structure for the first element

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez you should probably add some context about what you want the structure for, then. But *without using `for`*, `some_list[0]` gives you what you want.

Comment: just added context for the desired structure

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez if any of the answers below got you what you needed, make sure to accept the one you find is the best answer, so that this question isnt left unanswered. its not necessary, but suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, buddy. This should do it.

```
some_list = [['A001', 'A002'], ['A003', 'A004'], ['A005', 'A006']]

for i in range(len(some_list[0])):
    print(some_list[0][i])
```

Output:

```
A001
A002
```

Furthur on you can perform a nested loop operation for accessing them all. Just like this...

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    for j in range(len(some_list[i])):
        print(some_list[i][j])
```

Output:

```
A001
A002
A003
A004
A005
A006
```

Answer (score 1):

List indexing works like this:

```
>>> some_list=[['A001', 'A002'], ['A003', 'A004'], ['A005', 'A006']]
>>> some_list[0] # first sub list
['A001', 'A002']
>>> some_list[0][0] # first element in first sub list
'A001'
```

To get your desired output, try this:

```
some_list=[['A001', 'A002'], ['A003', 'A004'], ['A005', 'A006']]

for sub in some_list:
    print(sub)
    for ele in sub:
        print(ele)
```

Output:

```
['A001', 'A002']
A001
A002
['A003', 'A004']
A003
A004
['A005', 'A006']
A005
A006
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to print the individual elements of the first list, then it's just:

```
for i in some_list:
    print(i)
    for element in i:
        print(element)
```

Your talk of "structure" is confusing.  The structure of the first element is a list with 2 items.  It's important not to confuse the CONTENTS of an item with the REPRESENTATION of an item.  The first element contains ['A001','A002'].  It's up to you to decide how to print that.

Answer (score 1):

```
some_list=[['A001', 'A002'], ['A003', 'A004'], ['A005', 'A006']]

print(some_list[0])
```

Output: `['A001', 'A002']`

To access items inside this list:

```
for i in some_list[0]:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
A001
A002
```

So to do first loop and second loop thing:

```
for list_item in some_list:
    print(list_item)
    for item in list_item:
       print(item)
```